# how to put numbers into categories in python

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to the community and recently starting my project using 'python'

i have looked up the internet, but couldn't find quite the answer i want

```
duration_ms
3203
4583
7789
189654
512300
6523
42358
...
```

the list ranging from 5k~550k, and spread randomly
i tried to put these integers into categories like '0k~100k', '100k~150k',...,'550k~600k'

i tried make it into a variable then replace it but failed

```
time_dura= {
    '550k~600k':df['duration_ms']>=550000 and df['duration_ms']<600000,
    '500k~550k':df['duration_ms']>=500000 and df['duration_ms']<550000,
    '450k~500k':df['duration_ms']>=450000 and df['duration_ms']<500000,
...
```

i tried to used for loop...but

```
a={}
b={}
for i in df['duration_cat']:
    if df['duration_cat'][i]>= 550000:
        return {df['duration_cat'][a]:'550k~600k'}
    elif df['duration_cat'][i]>=500000:
        {df['duration_cat'][b]: '500k~550k'}
...
```

i will be appreciated if someone answer to this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `pd.cut`, but first you'll need to make your bins and the labels that correspond to those bins

Test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({"duration_ms": np.random.randint(10000, 590000, size=10)})

print(df)
   duration_ms
0       315711
1       445829
2       127952
3       162315
4       369783
5       314137
6       132579
7       458242
8       384564
9       320744
```

applied snippet

to mimic the inequality you've set up, we'll need to pass `right=False` to `pd.cut` to make the bins left inclusive and right exclusive

```
# create bins: [0, 100_000, 150_000, 200_000, ...]
bins = [0] + list(np.linspace(100_000, 600_000, 11)) 

# Creates a categorical column based on our bins
df["binned"] = pd.cut(df["duration_ms"], bins=bins, right=False)

# Repeat but use nicer looking labels than the defaults
labels = [f"{start/1000:.0f}k~{stop/1000:.0f}k" for start, stop in zip(bins, bins[1:])]
df["binned_labelled"] = pd.cut(df["duration_ms"], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

print(df)
   duration_ms                binned binned_labelled
0       315711  [300000.0, 350000.0)       300k~350k
1       445829  [400000.0, 450000.0)       400k~450k
2       127952  [100000.0, 150000.0)       100k~150k
3       162315  [150000.0, 200000.0)       150k~200k
4       369783  [350000.0, 400000.0)       350k~400k
5       314137  [300000.0, 350000.0)       300k~350k
6       132579  [100000.0, 150000.0)       100k~150k
7       458242  [450000.0, 500000.0)       450k~500k
8       384564  [350000.0, 400000.0)       350k~400k
9       320744  [300000.0, 350000.0)       300k~350k
```

Comment: it worked!! big thanks but i don't get the labels line, are you making a loop that goes through all the numbers in that column and convert them into stings?

Comment: The labels line is a little dense. I'm looping over the elements in `bins` (0, 100000, 150000, ...). And grabbing the current element as well as the element immediately to the right of that (these variables are labeled `start` and `stop`). So when I iterate, I first get `(0, 100000)`, and then `(100000, 150000)`, then `(150000, 200000)`, etc. For each of these values I divide them by 1000 and apply string formatting to remove the decimal to make them look pretty. So 1(0, 100000)` turns into `"0~100k"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to simplify the syntax:

```
time_dura= {
    '550k~600k':df[df['duration_ms'].between(550000, 60000-1)],
    '500k~550k':df[df['duration_ms'].between(500000, 550000-1)],
    '450k~500k':df[df['duration_ms'].between(450000, 500000-1)],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series([3203, 4583, 7789, 189654, 512300, 6523, 42358])
time_dura= {
    '550k~600k': series[(series >= 550000) & (series < 600000)],
    '500k~550k': series[(series >= 500000) & (series < 550000)],
    '450k~500k': series[(series >= 450000) & (series < 500000)],
}
```

or, if you want to do it more dynamically:

```py
starts = range(450, 600, 50)

time_dura = {}
for start in starts:
    stop = start + starts.step
    time_dura[f'{start}k~{stop}k'] = series[(series >= start * 1000) & (series < stop * 1000)]
```